# Unable to start the emulator (Genymotion)

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

when I click on start button in genymotion to booting the emulator It does not boot
I worked on it before and It was working but suddenly it stopped .

I tried to restart the windows but it does not work , what shall I do ?